# Singleton pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

The following snippet is straight forward,

```
public MyClass getInstance() {
    if(uniqueInstance == null) {
        uniqueInstance = new MyClass();
    }
    return uniqueInstance;
}
```

What does the following one do?

```
public MyClass getInstance() {
    if(uniqueInstance == null) {
        synchronized(MyClass.class) {
            uniqueInstance = new MyClass();
        }
    }
    return uniqueInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a poor attempt to make it threadsafe to prevent a race condition caused by at least two threads which have simultaneously entered the `if` block.

A bit more safe approach is adding an extra nullcheck, also known as [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

```
public MyClass getInstance() {
    if (uniqueInstance == null) {
        synchronized(MyClass.class) {
            if (uniqueInstance == null) {
                uniqueInstance = new MyClass();
            }
        }
    }
    return uniqueInstance;
}
```

However, I usually prefer [*Just Create One* pattern](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne) over Singleton.

Comment: "A bit more safe"... I wouldn't be too sure of that: http://www.google.ca/search?q=double+checked+locking+is+broken

Comment: @Karl: hence the *"a bit"*. It's also explained in the linked Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of insurance for thread safety.

From the javaworld article [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2002-01/02-qa-0125-singleton4.html?page=1):

> Synchronizing the method guarantees
>   that a call to the method cannot be
>   interrupted.

The main idea is that if you don't have the synchronized block it is possible for 2 threads to call the getInstance and reinitializing the object, thereby potentially losing any state data (if you should even have state data in a singleton)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO You should start with the simplest options first.  The simplest singleton is an enum with one entry.  Given that classes are load lazily, this will still give you lazy loading, unless to refer to the class directly and this doesn't happen by accident easily.

```
enum Singleton {
   INSTANCE;
}
```

To avoid accident loading you can use an inner class.

```
class Singleton {
    static class SingeltonHolder {
        static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Note; neither solution needs synchronization because they use the fact that class loading is thread safe.

In short; There are situations where locking is required, but don't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

The second one does the same thing, except: if you're using the first one, what happens if creating a new MyClass takes some amount of time, and during that time, someone else also calls MyClass.getInstance()?  You could potentially end up with two instances.  The second version locks the instantiation line, so that if another class tries to call at the same time, it will wait until the first is done.