# Sharing a class instance between all users with Tomcat

Tags: java, servlets

I have a class, called counter. It looks like this:

```
public class Counter {
  private int count;

  public Counter() {
    count = 1;
  }

  public int getCount(){
    return count;
  }

  public void incrementCount(){
    count++;
  }
```

I want to share a single instance of this between every user of a tomcat application.
So user 1 and user 2 would both see getCount() as the same value.
Assume for this that there is a technical reason why I can't store and read from a database.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Just create one](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne) and store it in the application scope during server's startup.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("counter", new Counter());
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way it's available in every servlet as follows:

```
Counter counter = (Counter) getServletContext().getAttribute("counter");
// ...
```

And in every JSP as follows:

```
<p>The count is ${counter.count}</p>
```

#### See also:

- [What's the difference between static methods and applying singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618212/what-is-the-difference-between-all-static-methods-and-applying-a-singleton-patter)
- [Synchronized singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357538/singleton-pattern)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your counter is not threadsafe. I'd suggest to use [`AtomicInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of `int`.

```
public class Counter {
  private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

  public Counter() {
    count.incrementAndGet();
  }

  public int getCount(){
    return count.get();
  }

  public void incrementCount(){
    count.incrementAndGet();
  }
}
```

Comment: Definitely. You don't want a singleton here.

Comment: Do I just put this into the package with the rest of the classes?

Comment: The listener? Yes truly it needs to be placed in the classpath like every other class you'd like to use in your webapp. I however assume that you're using Tomcat 7 which supports the new Servlet 3.0 annotations. Otherwise you have to get rid of `@WebListener` and declare the listener yourself in `web.xml` by `<listener>`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175726/how-do-i-load-a-java-class-not-a-servlet-when-the-tomcat-server-starts/4175742#4175742) for another example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern.

Try this:

```
public class Counter {
private int count;
private static Counter instance = null;
private static Object lockObj = new Object();



private Counter() {
count = 1;
}

public static Counter Instance(){
 synchronized(lockObj){
     if(instance == null){
        instance = new Counter();
     }
 }

 return instance;
}

public int getCount(){
return count;
}

public void incrementCount(){
count++;
}
}
```

and somewhere in your code you can use: `Counter.Instance().getCount()`

Comment: Thank you. Will that let me increment it too?

Comment: Yes, you need to call Counter.Instance().incrementCount()

Comment: Ofcourse you need to take care of synchronization across threads

Answer (score 2):

A singleton that works in Java with proper locking:

```
public class Counter {
  private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

  private static class Initilizer {
    private static Counter instance = new Counter();
  }

  private Counter() {}

  public Counter instance() { return Initilizer.instance; }

  public int getCount() { return counter.get() }
  public void increment() { counter.incrementAndGet(); }

}
```

get the count: `Counter.instance().getCount()`
increment:     `Counter.instance().increment()`

The difference between the 2 answers is the synchronization and singleton initialization which is optimized for java